# x509: certificate signed by unknown authority: Google Storage in Docker

Tags: docker, google-cloud-storage, nio

Running a tool that was hitting Google Storage from within Docker, I kept getting the following error: "x509: certificate signed by unknown authority".

I reviewed several articles that suggested [installing ca-certificates](https://github.com/google/go-github/issues/1049#issuecomment-454446363) would solve this problem for me, but doing so within my docker build had no effect.

How can I access Google Storage from within Docker?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In my particular case, the issue came about because I was using a default ubuntu:18.04 Docker image without the Google Cloud SDK installed.

When I instead switched to a Docker image that had the Google Cloud SDK preinstalled, such as gcr.io/cloud-genomics-pipelines/io, or if I installed the tools within the Ubuntu instance, this issue was resolved.

Answer (score 0):

Or in the alpine image, adding `ca-certificates` also worked for me:

```
RUN apk update && apk add ca-certificates && rm -rf /var/cache/apk/*
```